# Java library to calculate distances and angles from latitudes/longitudes on a sphere

Tags: library, java, geometry

I am looking for a java library to calculate with and transform locations `(lat, lon)`. Operations I want to perform on the sphere:

1. given two locations `x, y` I want to know the distance from `x` to `y`
2. given three locations `x, y, z` I want to know the angle between `x,y` and `y,z`
3. given two locations `x, y`, an angle `a` and a distance `d` I want to know a location `z` that is defined by the angle `a` to `x,y` and distance `d` from `y`

Is, e.g., `geotools` able to perform these operations?